# Error pip installing fbprophet, pystan installed fine, I tried different versions. My python is 3.6.7, tried all the answers suggested before

Tags: python, time-series, python-3.6, facebook-prophet, pystan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Q47.png)

I have attached a snapshot of the error msg. I am using python 3.6.7. I tried 3.7 and 3.8. pystan install successfully. I tried different versions of pystan as others suggested. I have been trying for a few days, googled all the answers and tried most to no avail. Others suggested using Anaconda, but I am trying to use pip install. Does fbprophet require a specific version of python?

Comment: Try `pip install wheel` first and then try installing prophet

Comment: I did try it, Wheel library installed fine, but I was still getting the error attached.

Comment: what is localpip. Are you running this on virtual env

Comment: Localpip was one of the suggested solutions. Basically, LocalPIP is an offline package manager for Python... It solves packages dependencies conflict issues and compiling errors. Internet access is required only for the first time of downloading LocalPIP repository. Once downloaded, you can install packages completely offline. It takes sometime to download and fix the issue as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I tried and worked for me! At this point I started to learn that finding the right versions to download to ur system is like unlocking/cracking a safe and u have to find the right combination. So here is what worked for me. A lot suggested to use older versions of pystan and fbprophet. The ones that worked for me were:

pip install pystan==2.18.0.0

pip install fbprophet==0.6

Make sure to download Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or a newer version, otherwise, you will get an error during installing fbprophet:

**"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": [http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools."](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools.%22)**

Here is the link to download it: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
It will download Visual Studio Installer for u, which will pick the necessary tools for u (about 6 Gb).
After that I was able to install fbprophet and import.
There are other suggestions like using Anaconda in other posts, or using a different version of pystan and fbprophet. Good luck!